# How to navigate from one page to another in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Ionic v1**

I was using `ui-sref` to simply navigate from one page to another in my ionic app, but recently have to switch to `$state.go` because pressing button closes the app. I figured it out that states are not maintained in `ui-sref`.

So my question is do I have to always use `$state.go` if I just want to simply navigate between pages without closing my app and create a separate function in controller to go to next page.

**Code for ref**

```
<button class=" button button-assertive" ui-sref="nextPage">Next</a>
```

or

```
<button class=" button button-assertive" ng-click="gotonext()">Next</a>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.gotonext = function(){  
    $state.go('nextPage')
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
$scope.gotonext = function(){  
    $location.path("/nextPage");
};
```

Comment: I am not looking for an alternative to `$state.go` I want to use `ui-sref` without states being lost. Hope you are getting what I want to acheive